# Defined constants as printf format argument, why is '+ 0' added?

Tags: c

I'm reading a book about C programming "*Advanced Programming In The Unix Environment*" and in the "*UNIX Standardization and Implementations*" chapter it shows a program that prints values for symbols in sysconf and pathconf, the code in this program has several lines that looks like this:

```
#ifdef ARG_MAX
    printf ("ARG_MAX defined to be %ld\n", (long) ARG_MAX + 0);
#else
    printf ("no symbol for ARG_MAX\n");
#endif
```

Whenever a defined constant is used as an argument for `printf` it's always followed by `+ 0`, it doesn't seem to be doing anything because I tried to remove it and nothing happened. What's the point of adding a zero?

Comment: I can think of two general uses of something like this, but they don't seem to be useful here: 1) to cause integral promotions, and 2) to create a value of an expression (that is not an lvalue).

Comment: I can think of another one: If you have `#define ARG_MAX`, it expands to `(long) + 0` (i.e. `0L`). I don't know how that would be possible (or why you would want to cater to it), though.

Comment: What edition of that book are you reading? It was originally written in 1992 when many aspects of C, Unix, and POSIX were poorly defined or poorly followed. It's probably a guard against some weird implementation, but I can't imagine what.

Comment: @Schwern I'm reading the 3rd edition

Comment: @Schwern: It's in my copy, with no explanation that I can find. I have the third edition, from 2013; I believe that's the latest.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The empty `#define` mentioned by [melpomene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1848654/melpomene) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41475949/defined-constants-as-printf-format-argument-why-is-0-added#comment70158081_41475949) is why the `+ 0` trick is used.

If some header has `#define ARG_MAX` (with no value) — an improbable but not impossible state of affairs — the code will still compile, though whether the output is useful is a separate discussion.  The blank replacement for `ARG_MAX` leaves `(long) + 0` which is still valid.  If, as you'd expect, the definition is an appropriately protected expression (probably within parentheses), adding `0` doesn't change the value.

In the ordinary course of events, when the preprocessor evaluates a conditional expression, any identifiers left over after expanding macros are mapped to zero (ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.10.1 Conditional inclusion):

> ¶4 … After all replacements due to macro expansion and the `defined` unary
>   operator have been performed, all remaining identifiers (including those lexically
>   identical to keywords) are replaced with the pp-number 0, and then each preprocessing
>   token is converted into a token. …

Although that's not immediately relevant to this question, it *is* why you sometimes see a conditional expression such as:

```
#if ARG_MAX + 0 > 131072
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because that code is autogenerated from an awk program.

> The awk(1) program shown in Figure 2.12 builds a C program that prints the value of each pathconf and sysconf symbol.

The important part of the program is this.

```
while (getline <"sysconf.sym" > 0) {
    printf("#ifdef %s\n", $1)
    printf("\tprintf(\"%s defined to be %%d\\n\", %s+0);\n", $1, $1)
    printf("#else\n")
    printf("\tprintf(\"no symbol for %s\\n\");\n", $1)
    printf("#endif\n")
    printf("#ifdef %s\n", $2)
    printf("\tpr_sysconf(\"%s =\", %s);\n", $1, $2)
    printf("#else\n")
    printf("\tprintf(\"no symbol for %s\\n\");\n", $2)
    printf("#endif\n")
}
```

Since it doesn't know what the symbol might contain, it's probably being defensive about it, though the book doesn't explain what its defending against.

Comment: I'm not sure that answers the question. The `+0` is in the C code because it's in the awk code -- but why is it in the awk code?

Comment: @KeithThompson Yeah, it's not an answer, but it's an important piece. The rest of the book doesn't appear to use the `+0`. I'm guessing it's there to prevent a segfault if the value is something weird, but I don't know what that value might be.

Comment: So perhaps it would be better as a comment.

Comment: @KeithThompson: the code would be inscrutable if presented in a comment.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yes, but the code isn't particularly relevant to the fact that the C code is generated by an awk script -- and that fact doesn't seem relevant to the question. Assuming your answer is correct (and it's certainly plausible), the C code would have used the same trick if it were written manually.